# Assign value to a class property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, oop

What am I doing wrong here when I need to assign a value to my class property in TypeScript but I'm getting an Error:
**`ERROR : uncaughtException: Cannot set property 'auth' of undefined`**

I need the property `auth` which initially doesn't keep any information(1) to hold the information I am assigning in my `done` method. But whenever I want to assign any value to that property it doesn't work in my case. I've checked many times and auth in done method is not undefined. It holds the information which is passed to it but anyway error pops up.

`Setters` and `Getters` don't help as well.

If I needed to assign this value in Angular it would definitely work but I guess there is some slight difference in use of Class.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import readline from "readline";
import { google } from "googleapis";
import path from 'path';
import { logger } from './winston';

class connectGoogleAPI {

    private SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
    ];

    private readonly token_path = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
    private readonly credential_path = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');
    private auth: any = 'value from auth';

    set _auth(auth: any) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    get _auth(): any {
        return this.auth;
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    private done(_a: any) {
        this.auth = _a;
        // this.auth = (_a as object);
        // console.log('done');

    }

    connect() {
        // console.log('connect');

        // Load client secrets from a local file.
        fs.readFile(this.credential_path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err: any, content: any) => {
            if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
            // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
            this.authorize(JSON.parse(content), this.done);
            // authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
        });
    }

    private authorize(credentials: any, callback: any) {
        // console.log('authorize');

        const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.web;
        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

        // Check if we have previously stored a token.
        fs.readFile(this.token_path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err: any, token: any) => {
            if (err) return this.getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
            logger.info(`Connected to Google API successfully`);
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    }

    private getNewToken(oAuth2Client: any, callback: any) {
        // console.log('getNewToken');

        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: this.SCOPES,
        });
        logger.warn('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });
        rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code: any) => {
            rl.close();
            oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err: any, token: any) => {
                if (err) return logger.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                fs.writeFile(this.token_path, JSON.stringify(token), (err: any) => {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);
                    logger.info('Token stored to', this.token_path);
                });
                return callback(oAuth2Client);
            });
        });

    }

    getAuth() {
        if (this.auth === null || this.auth === undefined) {
            logger.warn('Getting again auth - Google API');
            this.connect();
        }
        return this.auth;
    }

}

export const googleAPI = new connectGoogleAPI();
```

I would appreciate any help and hints.

*1. I already tried to assign some information in the constructor so it is not empty but it did work as well*

Comment: Remove your getter and setter and show us the code in which you call the done method.

Comment: @mamichels, I was just trying all possible ways to solve it and used getters and setters just in case. I am calling done method as a callback in my authorize method

Comment: @mamichels, it just came up to me. Can it be a problem of a scope? Should I just bind the class?

Comment: @mamichels, yes)) It was the issue) I just should put my thoughts on this post to realize the problem) I really appreciate your help and an attempt to give me a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the problem at first but the issue was in the scope. 
I called the method which was supposed to assign the value to the property as a callback function.

I forgot to bind the class to it) just in case somebody spent a lot of time coding and got tired to see it...

```
    connect() {
        // Load client secrets from a local file.
        fs.readFile(this.credential_path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err: any, content: any) => {
            if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
            // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
            this.authorize(JSON.parse(content), this.done.bind(this));
        });
    }
```